# How to set fixed size and position of a RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, layout, view, android-relativelayout

Android implemented a default layout rule, like measure, layout, etc, I didn't find out there is a method to set such a fixed size. How to get rid of that default layout behavior?

Actually, in my case, every view is supposed to be relative to its parent, and will have a specified size., how could I do?

Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if I correctly understood your issue, but you can specify size of certain View (e.g. RelativeLayout, LinearLayout or certain control). In Properties of your layout view (`Layout width`, `Layout height`) you do not need to use only `wrap_content` or `fill_parent`. You are also allowed to type size like `40dip`.

If you created your View dinamically, then you should set LayoutParams. For example, to define your element size and margins for RelativeLayout (similar for others) you should use something like:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adaptLayout = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(element_width, element_height);
adaptLayout.setMargins(marginLeft, marginTop, marginRight, marginBottom);
mLinearLayoutForm.setLayoutParams(adaptLayout);
```